# How to make a Custom Context Menu?

Tags: contextmenu, strip

i'm trying make a ContextMenu for my winForms App (VB.NET).

When i click on the form i want yo show a Fading Context Menu  (only a white rectangle with a label on it which we can hit and do an action)

So, i created an UserControl which inherits a Form, but when i call the Conectx menu my MainForm lost focus :s (im searching for something like a .Net contextMenuStrip)

an example image: http://s21.postimg.org/x3kcnt5ad/example.jpg